# Can't recognize math symbol - bold "minus" above variable

Tags: math-mode, symbols

I'm trying to "latex down" some Kalman equations and I'm not able find a way how to make that symbol above k variable in equation "Predict" (1) and (2) 
[image: picture]

For me, it seems like \bar{} but still I wasn't able to make it look like the same.

Comment: `\hat{x}^{-}_{k}` for example? It looks like a superscript minus symbol at first glance.

Comment: I agree with Christian that it appears to be a superscript.  If the minus sign is too wide, you could make it `P^\textrm{-}_{k}`, for example.

Comment: And welcome to TeX.SE!

Comment: this is almost certainly a superscript minus, and in the example shown, it looks too narrow to me.

Comment: Interesting notation.  I was taught to use $\hat{x}(k|k-1)$ for a prediction and $\hat{x}(k|k)$ for a correction.

Answer (score 4):

```
% arara: pdflatex

\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}
\[\hat{x}^{-}_{k}=A\hat{x}_{k-1}+Bu_k \]
\end{document}
```

[image]